# Index for the spatial distribution/segregation on a raster

Tags: qgis

Suppose I have two geotiff raster files for the two time periods t=1,2 where each pixel can get any value in the closed interval [0,1].

Can anyone suggest an index I could calculate to show the change in the spatial distribution of values, e.g. in t=1 pixels with values close to 1 (or at least ≠ 0) where more scattered, while in t=2 such pixels became less homogeneously distributed, i.e. inequality increased? I have stumbled upon the segreg plugin for QGIS, which allows to compute an array of segregation and diversity measures on spatial and non spatial modes, but I am not sure if this can be done with raster data.

Also, how can I calculate a metric which gives the change within the raster extent in the average pixel value?

I am using QGIS 2.18 on a Mac.